# in codeigniter Non-existent class: Commonlib is library file

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my library file
libraray file name   **Commonlib**

```
<?php
    class Commonlib extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $ci=& get_instance();
            $ci->load->database();

        }

        function getcountries()
        {
            return  $ci->db->get("countries")->result();
        }
    }
```

in config file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','Commonlib');
```

here is my view

```
$a = new Commonlib();
$results=$a->getcountries();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    // country_id
    echo '<a   href="#">'.$row->country .'</a><br>';
}
```

show this error    Non-existent class: 
where is trouble ? how to solve it ?

Comment: you can't extends library to CI_Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library name should be like this CI_Commonlib ... Please try.

Comment: in codeigniter v3 That is not required only the points to note is First lettler is capital & Class name & file name must match. For More https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here of naming convention. Because **Class names and file names must match.**

```
<?php
class Commonlib {

     public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
           $ci=& get_instance();
           $ci->load->database();

}
        function getcountries(){
            return  $ci->db->get("countries")->result();


        }
}
```

In view

```
 $a = new Commonlib();
   $results=$a->getcountries();
   foreach ($results as $row)
   { // country_id
       echo '<a   href="#">'.$row->country .'</a><br>';
   }
```

Comment: i change the cod as you write here then show this   Fatal error: Class 'CI_Commonlib' not found in D:\xamp\htdocs\worldtimeserver\system\core\Common.php on line 196

Answer (score 1):

go To your library and change it with this code.

```
<?php
class your_library_Name {

        function getcountries(){
            return  $ci->db->get("countries")->result();
        }
}
```

and this is how to call it

```
$rec= $this->your_library_Name->getcountries();
```

Comment: i change the code as you write here then show this  error    Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$Commonlib

Comment: replace commonlib to your own Library and load the library in autoload.php

Comment: class Commonlib {
       function getcountries(){
            return  $ci->db->get("countries")->result();
        }
}

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','Commonlib');

Comment: your code is work fine now just load this library  in your autoload.php file CI_Loader is the error of load file

Comment: $results=$this->Commonlib->getcountries();
   foreach ($results as $row)
   { 
       echo '<a   href="#">'.$row->country .'</a><br>';
   }

Comment: error is                       Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$Commonlib

Comment: is your library file name is  Commonlib

Comment: common lib is my file name and class name  same is Commonlib

Comment: Change the Class name to *Common* and same put *common* in your autoload.php

Comment: if it's work accept my answer Thanks. if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do any of a few things.

1. By default most people will just drop their library into `system/libraries`, and load it with either with the autoloader, or `$this->load->library()`. If you do this, you must prefix your class name with `CI_` so that CodeIgniter will recognize it, since the system folder is intended for stock files. In your case, you would need:

   ```
   class CI_Commonlib extends CI_Controller
   {
   }
   ```

This works, but it mixes your custom code into CodeIgniter system files, which can become very messy when you want to upgrade your installation.

2. My recommendation is to create a separate folder for your custom files, and then add that path to your loader object. You will not need to make any changes to the code if you move your `Commonlib` object to `application/libraries/Commonlib.php`.

People will often add custom objects to `system` when they want to share files between multiple CodeIgniter installations. Multiple applications can share the same `BASEPATH`, so it makes sense to put your code where the shared directory already exists.

3. The problem with this is the same issue with an upgrade path, where custom objects mix with stock code, and may get confusing. In this case defining your own shared folder can be very helpful. CodeIgniter lets you do that with `$this->load->add_package_path()` You can move your shared code into `custom/libraries` and be off to the races. In that case, you can update your controller (not view) accordingly.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

```
$this->load->add_package_path('custom/libraries');
$this->load->library('commonlib');
```